# Graph given with set of natural numbers

Tags: graph-theory

I'm given set B of first $2000$ natural numbers. Let $H$ be the graph which number of vertices is equal to $2^{2000}$(number of all subsets of B) and two vertices $u,v$ are neighbors if and only those two subsets are different and have non-empty intersection. Question is to check if $H^c$ is Eulerian, half-Eulerian and Hamiltonian. My logic is to first find number of edges in $H^c$ and then it is easy to find number of edges in $H$. So, using statement given above, two vertices in $H^c$ will be neighbors if and only two subsets have no common elements. Now if we take subset which contains $k$ element, then there is $2000-k \choose l$ where $l\in\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,2000-k\}$ so there is $2^{2000-k}$ sets that have no element in common with first set(or $2^{2000-k}$ vertices that are neighbors to fixed one). Can someone tell me whether this is correct, because now everything depends on $k$ which I am not sure is OK? Btw, I think that it is neither Hamiltonian, Euler because if $k=2000$ then there is only empty set that has no common elements with it. So we have leaf, it can't be Hamiltonian, also cant be Euler because not all vertices are even degrees.

Comment: From a quick read, it looks good. Your last two sentences really seem to be the most important piece to the question though so you might be able to ignore everything you wrote about $k$ (at least it looks that way)

Comment: Yes, but I also need to find number of edges in $H$ and $H^c$, not sure how to do it? Also, this graph is not half Euler right, because there is only one vertex of odd degree, and that is set B?

Comment: Correct, there only being one vertex of odd degree and at least one leaf rather answers all of your questions. As for the edge count, I think you are on the right path